# Trouble with marshal c# class to c++ structure

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

i have C++ structure

```
struct DressKey
{
int         keyId;                  
GENDER      gender;                 
DRESS_CLASS dressClass;             
unsigned int descriptor[KEY_SIZE];
float       confidence;             
short       keyLength;              
short       metric;                 

DressKey():
    keyId(0),
    gender(GENDER_UNDEFINED),
    dressClass(CLASS_UNDEFINED),
    confidence(0.0f),
    keyLength(KEY_SIZE),
    metric(0)
{
    descriptor[0] = 0;
}
```

};

Type of GENDER and DRESS_CLASS is enum

And i try pass it in method:

```
virtual ERROR_CODE ExtractDressKey(
    const unsigned char *frame,
    int width,
    int height,
    int lineLength,
    int format,
    DressKey *dressKey);
```

I have wrap this method and structure in c# at this way:

```
[DllImport("DSE.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.ThisCall, EntryPoint = "?ExtractDressKey@DSE@dse@@UEAA?AW4ERROR_CODE@2@PEBEHHHHPEAUDressKey@2@@Z")]
private static extern ERROR_CODE ExtractDressKey(IntPtr self, IntPtr frame, int width, int height, int lineLength, int format, ref DressKey dressKey);


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class DressKey
{

    public const int KEY_SIZE = 5768;
    public int keyId;                   //!< serialization key id
    public GENDER gender;                   //!< gender
    public DRESS_CLASS dressClass;              //!< dress category
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = KEY_SIZE)]
    public uint[] descriptor = new uint[KEY_SIZE];  //!< comparable part
    public double confidence;               //!< key confidence
    public short keyLength;             //!< actual numer of elements in descriptor
    public short metric;                    //!< ID of a metric revision
}
```

I got AccessViolationException. What is wrong in my wrapper?

**UPD**:

usage:

```
var imgPath = @"C:\1.jpg";

            using (var dse = new DSE())
            {
                using (var img = CV.LoadImageM(imgPath, LoadImageFlags.AnyColor))
                {
                    var subImg =  img;
                    using (subImg)
                    {
                        var dk = new DressKey();
                        var type = subImg.Channels == 1 ? 0 : 1;
                        var res = dse.ExtractDressKey(subImg.Data, subImg.Cols, subImg.Rows, subImg.Cols, type, ref dk);

                        if (res == ERROR_CODE.ERROR_OK)
                           Console.WriteLine("id={0}&key={1}", 123, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dk));
                        else
                        {
                           Console.WriteLine( res.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: `IntPtr self, IntPtr frame` vs `const unsigned char *frame` - why? Sjow also the call itself, not only declarations.

Comment: Why is ExtractDressKey virtual? I think that this is what is interfering with your call, as the C# code assumes a simple data-only class without virtual methods.

Comment: @AlexFarber IntPtr self is pointer to instace of class that contain this method

Comment: It is not a function at all.  It is a C++ member function pointer to a virtual method of a C++ class.  The rough equivalent of a C# delegate.  Very rough, C++ doesn't provide a way to encapsulate the required *this* pointer like a delegate does.  You cannot pinvoke this code, a C++/CLI wrapper is required that properly constructs the C++ object.

Comment: Arrays in C# are (almost?) always pointer-like, in C++ they can be literals.  Hmm.

Comment: @HansPassant Really? i add  in begin `cout<<"test"<<endl` of c++ function, and i see in console my `test`. Wrapper is work, but i pass wrong params, and function throw AccessViolationException

Answer (score 1):

You cannot expect to p/invoke C++ instance methods. P/invoke is used to call non-member functions. You need to do one of the following:

1. Wrap the C++ library in a mixed mode C++/CLI assembly, and have the C# code consume it as a managed reference.
2. Expose the C++ library using COM.
3. Wrap the C++ library in a C style procedural interface and access that using p/invoke.

Comment: You're wrong. [Proof](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18032/How-to-Marshal-a-C-Class)

Comment: No I am not wrong. Solution A is my option 3. Solution B is my option 1.

Comment: @DavidHeffeman I see,but solution A has two approaches to accessing the methods. Second approach is you option 2,but i use first approach (`CallingConvention.ThisCall`). I already use this feature in other projects, it's work for me

Comment: OK. Do it your way then.